# How to pass stderr to a command stream, then back to the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stderr

I'm using bash, but perhaps most shells behave similarly in this regard. If not, then my question pertains to bash.

There's a regularly used command that always issues a spurious error message (to stderr), but MAY sometimes issue error messages that are important. I figured I could pipe stderr to grep, then use -v option to filter the offending line that's otherwise noise. Whatever passes through the filter on stderr should go right back to the original destination (presumably the user's terminal). How do I do this?

(Getting the source and editing it to make a custom version that doesn't spit out that error is obviously possible but out of the question for practical reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output grep output to stderr.

```
thecommand 2> >(grep -v 'something' >&2)
```

Comment: Great! ... Dinner's ready, will try tomorrow!

Comment: No joy. :-( ... the youngest chown, when used with the old-school syntax, "warns", so, that's a good candidate example: chown postgres.postgres backups/* 2> (grep -v 'warning' >&2)  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' Hmmm... By the way, you have a space missing after the > and before the (

Comment: Fixed it For Ya! ;-)

Comment: I do not understand. The command is correct and works as is. The should be no space between `>` and `(`, as it is a process substitution. There should be no slashes in front of `(` `)`.

Comment: That's VERY curious?! When I tried it your way I got the error I indicated - "unexpected token", and when I gave it the backslashes it worked fine! Further, without the space between > and (, it says, "chown: cannot access '2/dev/fd/63': No such file or directory"  So... IDK what's going on differently between our versions! Just a sec - I'll get my version info. ...It's GNU bash, version 5.2.9(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) and literally installed Sunday, less than 48 hours ago! Maybe the answer needs two parts? Hmmm...

Comment: I would guess that you are executing the command via ssh or `bash -c` or other wrapper that applies additional quoting. If you executed `>\(`, consider checking if a file named `(` literally was created in your current directory.

Comment: Well, I HAVE sshed into the box but that bash is from the system I'm running it on, so I don't think your suggestion there applies, however you were / are CORRECT ... I have both a file named 2) and another named (grep  ! WOW! Thanks for catching that! ... OK, so what's the complaint about the ( all about then? I've never had that problem that I can remember, and I've been using bash since at least 1989! (not that I'm any expert, obviously!)

Comment: The code, as presented, I tested online on tutorialspoint  http://tpcg.io/_G1W3AL

Comment: Looks like Chepner fixed it: They returned it to your version AND added another > character (with interveining space), and THAT works! YAY!